# Client Side validation on Backbone.js collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm using backbone-on-rails gem and got the following:

Model

```
class Crayons.Models.Color extends Backbone.Model
  validate: (attrs) ->
    if attrs.colorname.length == 0 
      return "colorname can't be empty"
```

Collection

```
class Crayons.Collections.Color extends Backbone.Collection
  url: '/api/colors'
```

collection is created in a router

```
  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Crayons.Collections.Color()
    @collection.fetch()
```

Methods in ColorIndex

```
  createCrayonId: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    val = new Crayons.Models.Color()
    val.on("error", @errorHandling);
    val.set(colorname: $('#new_color_name').val())
    @collection.create colorid: val.get("colorname");
    $('#new_color')[0].reset()

  errorHandling: (model, event) ->
    alert(event)
```

I have a simple validation that shows an alert when the length is zero. However, after the alert box, the items are still being added to the collection because of `@collection.create colorid: val.get("colorname");`

What can I do to stop the collection from adding the results in it when an error has been caught?

**Update1**
Short term solution is below and it works but I'm unsure if its a correct way of doing things

```
ok = val.set(colorname: $('#new_video_url').val())
if ok
  @collection.create colorname: val.get("colorname");
```

**Update2**

```
class Crayons.Collections.Colors extends Backbone.Collection
  url: '/api/videos'
  model: new Crayons.Models.Color()
  validate: (attrs) ->
    if attrs.colorname.length == 0 
      return "colorname can't be empty"
```

**Correct way**
The validate function should be in the model and function that alerts the error should be initialized on the model.

```
class Crayons.Models.Color extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: -> 
    this.bind("error", @errorHandling)

  errorHandling: (model, event) ->
    alert(event)

  validate: (attrs) ->
    #your error validation goes here
```

Now the method in index is quite simple

```
  createCrayonId: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @collection.create colorname: $('#new_color_name').val()
```

Comment: is your collection a collection of colors or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation triggers for the color model but not for the collection model. So if you wanted to do it the clean way you should add a validation for the collection model to check if colorId is valid, same in the update with videoid.

You can set a model property of a collection and the when creating/saving a collection model it will use this model's validation to determine if it should create/save the model or not

Comment: I've tried doing that in update2 but I think I'm not setting the model correctly on the collection and as a result the application doesn't load. can you please suggest how to set the model in a collection?

Comment: dont use `new` when setting model property - you should just pass a reference to the constructor so `Crayons.Models.Color` is enough

Comment: ah and Collections dont have a validate method - model validation is used when saving/creating collection models

Comment: schweet. got it. updated the answer with more info. thanks for help